# CakePHP view action

Tags: php, cakephp

Go easy, I'm just starting to learn CakePHP.

I'm having to ask this question because i dont really feel Cake has the greatest documentation.

I have the simplest of code:

```
function view($id = NULL){
    $this->Post->id = $id;
    $this->set('post',$this->Post->read());
}
```

What i'm asking is what *exactly* is `$this->Post->id = $id;` doing? I understand what is being *assigned* but i'm a little unclear of what it's being *assigned to*.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The controller holds an instance of the corresponding model. So `$this->Post` is the instance of the model, which is accessible from the controller. This is an istance of the model `Post`, which inherits from `AppModel`, which in turn inherits from `Model`. As such it has a public property `id`, inherited from `Model`, and you get this property by `$this->Post->id`.

The object relational mapping of CakePHP assures you that when you call the method `$this->Post->read()`, you will retrieve the data stored in the table associated to the model `Post`, in the column identified by the id `$id`.

Comment: ok so if i knew i had a column called "name" how would i change this function to only grab one record with corresponding value in "name". If that makes sense?

Comment: It would work if name is your primary key. Otherwise you would have to use the `find` method instead of `read`

Comment: CakePHP's models also give you a set of convenience methods in the form findBy<ColumnName>. So you could call findByName($name) to retrieve the corresponding record.